# How to check whether a scheme of finite type over Spec Z is regular or not

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $f_1, f_2, \ldots f_k$ be a set of polynomials in $n$ variables, with integer coefficients. These define an affine scheme $X$ of finite type over $Spec \mathbb{Z}$. (We could also consider homogeneous polynomials, and the associated projective scheme.)

Question: How do I check (by hand or by computer) whether this scheme is regular or not?

A necessary but not sufficient condition is that the generic fiber $X_\mathbb{Q}$ is smooth as a variety over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is something we can check by the Jacobian criterion.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but I think it would be easier to check whether the scheme is smooth over $\textrm{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$.